# Cron job update csv, need help solving :-)

Tags: php, csv

Okay so my question is as follow:

I have a big csv file containing alot of products ranked after id, price, stock etc, this file updates every hour via a link. On the other hand i have a csv file containg a few products listed after the same properties.

What code do i need to write to search in the big file after the products i have on the other csv, and then import the changes to the small csv? Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but you're going to have to be more specific about "changes", if there was a before/after or some market for what had changed then that part would be super easy, otherwise it's impossible to say from just the information available. The answer will depend almost entirely on what your CSVs contain. It may be that you need to completely rebuild the small CSV fresh every hour. Otherwise, I;m not sure what this has to do with WP, reading and writing CSV files is generic PHP, as are cron jobs. Generic PHP Q's go on stackoverflow